# Resizing bitmap for CreatePatternBrush when printing

Tags: winapi, printing, gdi

I am trying to print a brush pattern like I see on the screen but I get different results depending on the printer DC.  I use Microsoft PDF or a printer.  Both are printing using 600 DPI.  I'm trying to get the same pattern when I'm printing by resizing the bitmap that is being used by CreatePatternBrush.  This seems to work fine for Microsoft PDF but not for the printer.  The pattern using the printer is way too large.  Any clue why?

OnBnClickedButtonprint is where I'm trying to print where ScaleBitmap is done on the pattern bitmap. Here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Printing.h"
#include "PrintingDlg.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

RECT rcSmall    = { 25, 25, 75, 75 };
RECT rcBig      = { 55, 55, 255, 255 };
RECT rcWholeArea = { 0, 0, 300, 300 };

COLORREF crRed      = RGB(255, 0, 0);
COLORREF crGreen    = RGB(0, 255, 0);
COLORREF crBlue     = RGB(0, 0, 255);
COLORREF crWhite    = RGB(255, 255, 255);
COLORREF crBlack    = RGB(0, 0, 0);

CPrintingDlg::CPrintingDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(IDD_PRINTING_DIALOG, pParent)
{
    WORD HatchBits[8] = { 0xfe, 0xfe, 0xfe, 0xfe, 0xfe, 0xfe, 0xfe, 0xfe };
    m_hBitmap = ::CreateBitmap(8, 8, 1, 1, HatchBits);
}

void CPrintingDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CPrintingDlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTONPRINT, &CPrintingDlg::OnBnClickedButtonprint)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CPrintingDlg message handlers

BOOL CPrintingDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

HBITMAP CPrintingDlg::ScaleBitmap(HDC hdc, HBITMAP hBitmapSrc)
{
    double gDPIScaleX = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSX) / 96.0f;
    double gDPIScaleY = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY) / 96.0f;

    if (gDPIScaleX == 1.0 && gDPIScaleY == 1.0)
        return hBitmapSrc;

    // Get logical coordinates
    BITMAP bm;
    ::GetObject(hBitmapSrc, sizeof(bm), &bm);

    int iWidth = (int)(bm.bmWidth * gDPIScaleX);
    int iHeight = (int)(bm.bmHeight * gDPIScaleY);

    // Select the source DC
    HDC hdcSrc = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP hBitmapOldSrc = (HBITMAP)::SelectObject(hdcSrc, hBitmapSrc);

    // Create the bitmap and select the destination DC
    HDC hdcDst = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP hBitmapDst = ::CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcDst, iWidth, iHeight);
    HBITMAP hBitmapOldDst = (HBITMAP)::SelectObject(hdcDst, hBitmapDst);

    // Resize
    ::StretchBlt(hdcDst, 0, 0, iWidth, iHeight, hdcSrc, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, SRCCOPY);

    // Reselect the old bitmaps
    ::SelectObject(hdcSrc, hBitmapOldSrc);
    ::SelectObject(hdcDst, hBitmapOldDst);

    // Delete the resources
    DeleteDC(hdcSrc);
    DeleteDC(hdcDst);

    return hBitmapDst;
}

RECT CPrintingDlg::ScaleRect(HDC hdc, RECT rcOriginal)
{
    double gDPIScaleX = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSX) / 96.0f;
    double gDPIScaleY = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY) / 96.0f;

    if (gDPIScaleX == 1.0 && gDPIScaleY == 1.0)
        return rcOriginal;

    RECT rcScaled;

    rcScaled.left = (long)(rcOriginal.left * gDPIScaleX);
    rcScaled.right = (long)(rcOriginal.right * gDPIScaleX);
    rcScaled.top = (long)(rcOriginal.top * gDPIScaleY);
    rcScaled.bottom = (long)(rcOriginal.bottom * gDPIScaleY);

    return rcScaled;
}

void CPrintingDlg::DrawRectangle(HDC hdc, RECT rect, COLORREF cr)
{
    HPEN hPen = ::CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, cr);
    ::SelectObject(hdc, hPen);

    HBRUSH hBrush = ::CreateSolidBrush(cr);
    ::SelectObject(hdc, hBrush);

    ::Rectangle(hdc, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom);
}

void CPrintingDlg::DrawPatternRectangle(HDC hdc, HBITMAP hBitmap, RECT rect, COLORREF cr)
{
    int oldROP2 = 0;

    HPEN hPen = ::CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, crBlack);
    ::SelectObject(hdc, hPen);

    HBRUSH hPatternBrush = ::CreatePatternBrush(hBitmap);
    ::SelectObject(hdc, hPatternBrush);

    ::SetTextColor(hdc, crBlack);
    if (::GetROP2(hdc) == R2_COPYPEN)
    {
        ::SetBkColor(hdc, crWhite);
        oldROP2 = ::SetROP2(hdc, R2_MASKNOTPEN);
        ::Rectangle(hdc, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom);

        ::SetBkColor(hdc, cr);
        ::SetROP2(hdc, R2_MERGEPEN);
        ::Rectangle(hdc, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom);

        ::SetROP2(hdc, oldROP2);
    }
    else
    {
        ::SetBkColor(hdc, cr);
        ::Rectangle(hdc, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom);
    }
}

void CPrintingDlg::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC hdc(this);

    DrawRectangle(hdc, rcWholeArea, crWhite);
    DrawRectangle(hdc, rcSmall, crGreen);
    DrawPatternRectangle(hdc, m_hBitmap, rcBig, crRed);
}

void CPrintingDlg::OnBnClickedButtonprint()
{
    CPrintDialog dlgPrint(FALSE, PD_NOSELECTION);
    dlgPrint.GetDefaults();
    dlgPrint.m_pd.Flags &= ~PD_RETURNDEFAULT;

    DEVMODE* dm = (DEVMODE*)GlobalLock(dlgPrint.m_pd.hDevMode);
    dm->dmFields |= DM_ORIENTATION;
    dm->dmOrientation = DMORIENT_LANDSCAPE;
    GlobalUnlock(dlgPrint.m_pd.hDevMode);

    dlgPrint.DoModal();
    HDC hdc = dlgPrint.GetPrinterDC();

    DOCINFO docInfo;
    ZeroMemory(&docInfo, sizeof(docInfo));
    docInfo.cbSize = sizeof(docInfo);
    docInfo.lpszDocName = _T("PrintTest");

    StartDoc(hdc, &docInfo);
    StartPage(hdc);

    DrawRectangle(hdc, ScaleRect(hdc, rcWholeArea), crWhite);
    DrawRectangle(hdc, ScaleRect(hdc, rcSmall), crGreen);
    DrawPatternRectangle(hdc, ScaleBitmap(hdc, m_hBitmap), ScaleRect(hdc, rcBig), crRed);

    EndPage(hdc);
    EndDoc(hdc);

    DeleteDC(hdc);
}
```

Here is what I'm trying to print:

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that a true printer DC uses a different mapping mode. Try calling [GetMapMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144897.aspx) to see, if they return different values for the Microsoft Print to PDF printer, and a real printer.

Comment: Nope, both are set to MM_TEXT

Comment: Not related to your issue, but you have a resource leak. You need to free the bitmap returned by `ScaleBitmap()`.